# decompose the radical of an ideal as an intersection of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the ideal $I=\langle x^4-x^3z-xy^2+y^2z,xy^2-xz-y^2z+z^2 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

**Question :** Decompose the radical $\sqrt{I}$ as a finite intersection of prime ideals.

**My Attempt :** I can see that $I=\langle (x^3-y^2)(x-z),(y^2-z)(x-z) \rangle$. So $V(I)=V(x-z) \cup V(x^3-y^2,y^2-z)$ and hence $I(V(I))=I(V(x-z)) \cap I(V(x^3-y^2,y^2-z))$.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, we have $\sqrt{I}=I(V(I))$ by Nullstellensatz. Since $V(x-z)$ is irreducible, we have $I(V(x-z))$ is prime. I want to do the same thing to the ideal $I(V(x^3-y^2,y^2-z))$ but I am not able to show $V(x^3-y^2,y^2-z)$ is irreducible. Or, **is this algebraic set irreducible?**

Can anyone help me with this step?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3-y^2,y^2-z)\simeq\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$ which is an integral domain since $x^3-y^2$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

$$V(x^3-y^2)=\{(t^2,t^3):t\in\Bbb C\}$$
(to see this let $t=y/x$ on a typical point of the variety). Then
$$V(x^3-y^2,y^2-z)=\{(t^2,t^3,t^6):t\in\Bbb C\}.$$
This is the image of $\Bbb A^1(\Bbb C)$ under an algebraic map,
so is irreducible.

Comment: What do you mean by an algebraic map?

Comment: "this is the image of $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$ under an algebraic map, so is irreducible". Is this a theorem? Can I find this result in a textbook?

Comment: Image of an irreducible set under a continuous map is irreducible - this is a general topology result.

Alternatively, you want to show that the coordinate ring of $V(x^3 - y^2, y^2-z)$ is a domain. But $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3-y^2, y^2-z) \cong \mathbb{C}[t^2, t^3, t^6] \subset \mathbb{C}[t]$, hence is a domain.